# toPrecision is not a function when trying to use toPrecision

Tags: javascript, jquery

What did I miss?

**Error**

```
TypeError: $(...).val(...).toPrecision is not a function
```

**Code**

```
$('.value_psi').val(
    convert(Number($('.value_psi').val()), "psi", "bar")
 ).toPrecision(4);
```

**Update**

convert returns:

```
return val * conv[from] / conv[to];
```

**Solution thoughts**

so solution was basically to move one of the parenthesis to the right!

Comment: Are you sure the result of convert returns a number? Not a string?

Comment: `toPrecision` only works on numbers.  When passing a parameter to `.val()`, it *sets* the value and returns a jQuery object.  If you called `.val()` with no parameters, to *get* the value, it'd return a string.  Neither strings nor jQuery objects have a `.toPrecision()` method.

Comment: Xenyal: ... if there was a way to return types on jQuery, I'd know.  Right now I presume it returns a string

Answer (score 4):

When used like that, the `val` methods return a jQuery object. The `toPrecision` method is a method on the `Number` object, not a jQuery method.

Trying to access it on a jQuery object will return `undefined`, and then trying to use that as a function gives you the error message.

To format the number that you use in the `val` method, you would use `toPrecision` on the value inside the call, not on the return value from the call:

```
$('.value_psi').val(
  convert(Number($('.value_psi').val()), "psi", "bar").toPrecision(4)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you're using `.val()` as setter method and that return the `input` jQuery object it self. So you can't apply `toPrecision()` on that. [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) applied to [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object.

You need to apply `toPrecision` on `convert()` returned value.

```
$('.value_psi').val(convert(Number($('.value_psi').val()), "psi", "bar").toPrecision(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.val()` as a setter method, it returns the jQuery object, not the value. That is the reason for the error.

But if there are multiple inputs with the "value_psi" class, there is another issue. When you use `.val()` as a setter method, it sets the value of all the elements, but when you use `.val()` as a getter method, it gets the value of the first element. That means the code in the other answers will set all the inputs using the value of the first input.

To fix this, you can use the version of the `.val()` method that takes a function. The function is executed for each input in the jQuery object. The second parameter to the function is the current value of the input. (The first parameter is an index.) The function should return the new value for the input.

```
$('.value_psi').val(function(i, value) {
    return convert(Number(value), "psi", "bar").toPrecision(4);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting Error in this pattern`give=give.toPrecision(4);`

Solution: 
Try to do in this pattern
`give=Number(give.toPrecision(4));`

hope it works...!